# Bound rational function for epsilon delta proof

Tags: calculus

Find $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\sqrt{x}}{x+1}$ using the epsilon delta method.

I get to the point where $ \left| x \right| \left| \frac{1}{x+1} \right| \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right| < \epsilon $ and I'm stuck there because $ \left| \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right|$ can't be bounded from above.

Comment: $|x||\frac 1{\sqrt x}| = \sqrt x$.

Comment: Doesn't |x| have to be in the equation for me to say delta must be 1

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, but if you need delta to be $\le 1$ or $\le 1000$ or $\le \frac 1{10^{100}}$ you can just *choose* it to have that restriction. You want to prove that there is a $\delta$ so that for all $x: |x-a|<\delta$ you can choose delta to be as small as you like because if its true for one delta, it will be true for all smaller delta.  If $Q$ is true for all $x\in\{x:|x-a|<\delta\}$ and $\delta_2<\delta$ then $\{x:|x-a|<\delta_2\}\subset\{x:|x-a|<\delta\}$ so $Q$ is true for all $x: |x-a|<\delta_2$.

Answer (score 1):

For $\sqrt x$ to be defined as a real number you have to take limit as $x \to 0$ through positive values. Now just note that $0 <\frac {\sqrt x} {1+x} <\sqrt x <\epsilon$ if $x <\epsilon^{2}$.